# How to pipe/forward seamlessly from port 80 to port XXXX with go?

Tags: go

I have a bunch of websites running on one server (single IP) and they all run on high ports so I don't need root to run them.

When someone visits from one web address, lets say, http://address001.com/, I want to seamlessly pipe the data from port 4444 to the person who made this request, and if someone visits http://address002.com/ I want to pipe the data from port 5555.

How would I do this in Go?

So far I have a handler function that looks like this:

```
func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {                      
  if strings.Contains(r.Host, "address001") {                    
    // ???
  }                                                                      
}
```

Comment: Won't it be easier to just use `nginx` to proxy the request to the process you want it to go?

Comment: No it won't, I've done it like that.

Comment: What you've described here is simpler with nginx, apache, caddy, etc. What do you need to do differently? If you do need to write a reverse proxy, what from the multitude of online examples doesn't work?

Comment: Setting up nginx is much more of a pain because then I have to deal with the configuration and a whole other service running, not to mention all the extra attack area. I did this with Go once before and it was a one liner I just can't remember how I did it.

Comment: Your Go proxy will also be "a whole other service running", so that's no different. Are you really suggesting that writing and maintaining an entire stable, secure, working, performant application is easier than configuring nginx?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's a few lines of code compared to running a giant service that requires me to re-familiarize my self with the configuration syntax. Nginx is not a part of my current stack and would need to be run through Systemd, whereas I currently have a stack thats 100% Go. Why install nginx, re-learn how to configure it, and them set up the systemd service when I already know Go? Why add extra attack surface area for something I can do my self? Why needlessly complicate my stack with a huge server framework? Writing and maintaining a Go application is pretty easy imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use httputil's [ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy)

here's an example code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
)

func main() {
    director := func(req *http.Request) {
        switch req.Host {
        case "address001.com":
            req.URL.Host = "localhost:4444"
            req.URL.Scheme = "http"
        case "address002.com":
            req.URL.Host = "localhost:5555"
            req.URL.Scheme = "http"
        default:
            log.Println("error")
        }
    }
    proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}
    log.Fatalln(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", proxy))
}
```